# LAPACK SVD (Singular Value Decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, svd

Do yo know any example to use LAPACK To calculate SVD?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The routine [`dgesdd`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesdd.f) computes the SVD for a double precision matrix.  Do you just need an example of how to use it?  Have you tried reading the documentation?

An example using the C LAPACK bindings (note that I wrote this just now, and haven't actually tested it.  Also note that the exact types for arguments to clapack vary somewhat between platforms so you may need to change `int` to something else):

```
#include <clapack.h>

void SingularValueDecomposition(int m,     // number of rows in matrix
                                int n,     // number of columns in matrix
                                int lda,   // leading dimension of matrix
                                double *a) // pointer to top-left corner
{
    // Setup a buffer to hold the singular values:
    int numberOfSingularValues = m < n ? m : n;
    double *s = malloc(numberOfSingularValues * sizeof s[0]);

    // Setup buffers to hold the matrices U and Vt:
    double *u = malloc(m*m * sizeof u[0]);
    double *vt = malloc(n*n * sizeof vt[0]);

    // Workspace and status variables:
    double workSize;
    double *work = &workSize;
    int lwork = -1;
    int *iwork = malloc(8 * numberOfSingularValues * sizeof iwork[0]);
    int info = 0;

    // Call dgesdd_ with lwork = -1 to query optimal workspace size:
    dgesdd_("A", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &m, vt, &n, work, &lwork, iwork, &info);
    if (info) // handle error conditions here

    // Optimal workspace size is returned in work[0].
    lwork = workSize;
    work = malloc(lwork * sizeof work[0]);

    // Call dgesdd_ to do the actual computation:
    dgesdd_("A", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &m, vt, &n, work, &lwork, iwork, &info);
    if (info) // handle error conditions here

    // Cleanup workspace:
    free(work);
    free(iwork);

    // do something useful with U, S, Vt ...

    // and then clean them up too:
    free(s);
    free(u);
    free(vt);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example using dgesdd?

Comment: @darkcminor: in Fortran or C or what?  And again: have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Also see the intel example: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lapack/mkl_lapack_examples/dgesdd_ex.c.htm

Comment: `double *work = workSize` should be `double *work = &workSize`.