# Calling MATLAB's built-in LAPACK/BLAS routines

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, lapack, blas

I want to learn how to call the built-in LAPACK/BLAS routines in MATLAB. I have experience in MATLAB and mex files but I've actually no idea how to call LAPACK or BLAS libraries. I've found the gateway routines in [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack) that simplifies the calls since I don't have to write a mex file for any function such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047503/lapack-svd-singular-value-decomposition). I need any toy example to learn the basic messaging between MATLAB and these built-in libraries. Any toy example such as matrix multiplication or LU decomposition is welcome.

Comment: Why FORTRAN? I am not sure but I always thought that LAPACK/BLAS have been ported to C/C++ 30 years ago and MATLAB uses this implementation!

Comment: Well, you see that I'm so new to it :( I see FORTRAN codes when I check for their documentation. Let me update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mikhail, @Ismail: They libraries themselves are written in Fortran, and the calling conventions are those of Fortran. You are right that there are wrappers for C/C++, CBLAS/ CLAPACK being the most straightforward ones, and then a bunch of templated/generic/whatever things for C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look inside the *[lapack.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack/content/lapack.m)* file from the FEX submission mentioned, you will see a couple of examples on how to use the function:

#### Example: SVD decomposition using [DGESVD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dgesvd.f.html):

```
X = rand(4,3);
[m,n] = size(X);
C = lapack('dgesvd', ...
     'A', 'A', ...           % compute ALL left/right singular vectors
      m, n, X, m, ...        % input MxN matrix
      zeros(n,1), ...        % output S array
      zeros(m), m, ...       % output U matrix
      zeros(n), n, ....      % output VT matrix
      zeros(5*m,1), 5*m, ... % workspace array
      0 ...                  % return value
);
[s,U,VT] = C{[7,8,10]};      % extract outputs
V = VT';
```

*(Note: the reason we used those dummy variables for output variables is because Fortran functions expect all arguments to be passed by reference, but MEX-functions in MATLAB do not allow modifying their input, thus it's written to return copies of all inputs in a cell array with any modifications)*

We get:

```
U =
     -0.44459      -0.6264     -0.54243       0.3402
     -0.61505     0.035348      0.69537      0.37004
     -0.41561     -0.26532      0.10543     -0.86357
     -0.50132      0.73211     -0.45948    -0.039753
s =
       2.1354
      0.88509
      0.27922
V =
     -0.58777      0.20822     -0.78178
      -0.6026     -0.75743      0.25133
     -0.53981      0.61882      0.57067
```

Which is equivalent to MATLAB's own [SVD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) function:

```
[U,S,V] = svd(X);
s = diag(S);
```

that gives:

```
U =
     -0.44459      -0.6264     -0.54243       0.3402
     -0.61505     0.035348      0.69537      0.37004
     -0.41561     -0.26532      0.10543     -0.86357
     -0.50132      0.73211     -0.45948    -0.039753
s =
       2.1354
      0.88509
      0.27922
V =
     -0.58777      0.20822     -0.78178
      -0.6026     -0.75743      0.25133
     -0.53981      0.61882      0.57067
```

---

## EDIT:

For completeness, I show below an example of a MEX-function directly calling the Fortran interface of the DGESVD routine.

The good news is that MATLAB provides `libmwlapack` and `libmwblas` libraries and two corresponding header files `blas.h` and `lapack.h` we can use. In fact, there is a page in the documentation explaining the process of [calling BLAS/LAPACK functions from MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-lapack-and-blas-functions-from-mex-files.html).

In our case, `lapack.h` defines the following prototype:

```
extern void dgesvd(char *jobu, char *jobvt, 
  ptrdiff_t *m, ptrdiff_t *n, double *a, ptrdiff_t *lda,
  double *s, double *u, ptrdiff_t *ldu, double *vt, ptrdiff_t *ldvt,
  double *work, ptrdiff_t *lwork, ptrdiff_t *info);
```

#### svd_lapack.c

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "lapack.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSignedIndex m, n, lwork, info=0;
    double *A, *U, *S, *VT, *work;
    double workopt = 0;
    mxArray *in;

    /* verify input/output arguments */
    if (nrhs != 1) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("One input argument required.");
    }
    if (nlhs > 3) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");
    }
    if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input matrix must be real double matrix.");
    }

    /* duplicate input matrix (since its contents will be overwritten) */
    in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);

    /* dimensions of input matrix */
    m = mxGetM(in);
    n = mxGetN(in);

    /* create output matrices */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, m, mxREAL);
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((m<n)?m:n, 1, mxREAL);
    plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, n, mxREAL);

    /* get pointers to data */
    A = mxGetPr(in);
    U = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    S = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    VT = mxGetPr(plhs[2]);

    /* query and allocate the optimal workspace size */
    lwork = -1;
    dgesvd("A", "A", &m, &n, A, &m, S, U, &m, VT, &n, &workopt, &lwork, &info);
    lwork = (mwSignedIndex) workopt;
    work = (double *) mxMalloc(lwork * sizeof(double));

    /* perform SVD decomposition */
    dgesvd("A", "A", &m, &n, A, &m, S, U, &m, VT, &n, work, &lwork, &info);

    /* cleanup */
    mxFree(work);
    mxDestroyArray(in);

    /* check if call was successful */
    if (info < 0) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Illegal values in arguments.");
    } else if (info > 0) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Failed to converge.");
    }
}
```

On my 64-bit Windows, I compile the MEX-file as: `mex -largeArrayDims svd_lapack.c "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmwlapack.lib"`

Here is a test:

```
>> X = rand(4,3);
>> [U,S,VT] = svd_lapack(X)
U =
   -0.5964    0.4049    0.6870   -0.0916
   -0.3635    0.3157   -0.3975    0.7811
   -0.3514    0.3645   -0.6022   -0.6173
   -0.6234   -0.7769   -0.0861   -0.0199
S =
    1.0337
    0.5136
    0.0811
VT =
   -0.6065   -0.5151   -0.6057
    0.0192    0.7521   -0.6588
   -0.7949    0.4112    0.4462
```

vs.

```
>> [U,S,V] = svd(X);
>> U, diag(S), V'
U =
   -0.5964    0.4049    0.6870    0.0916
   -0.3635    0.3157   -0.3975   -0.7811
   -0.3514    0.3645   -0.6022    0.6173
   -0.6234   -0.7769   -0.0861    0.0199
ans =
    1.0337
    0.5136
    0.0811
ans =
   -0.6065   -0.5151   -0.6057
    0.0192    0.7521   -0.6588
   -0.7949    0.4112    0.4462
```

*(remember that the sign of the eigenvectors in `U` and `V` is arbitrary, so you might get flipped signs comparing the two)*

Comment: @Acorbe: I added an implementation of a MEX-file that directly calls the Fortran functions, so you can try it yourself and compare the speed... I did a quick test, and MATLAB's own `svd` is about twice as fast. I think this in part due to the overhead of calling MEX-functions as opposed to a builtin function. The advantage of the mentioned FEX submission is that you don't have to write a MEX-file for each LAPACK routine, their solution takes care of all the boilerplate code for you, into a single function!

Answer (score -2):

A good/pratical example of how to use SVD in matlab is explained here:
[Transforming captured co-ordinates into screen co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689839/transforming-captured-co-ordinates-into-screen-co-ordinates/1689899#1689899)

More on how to calculate svd in objective-c with lapack is written here [calculate the V from A = USVt in objective-C with SVD from LAPACK in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891769/calculate-the-v-from-a-usvt-in-objective-c-with-svd-from-lapack-in-xcode)

Comment: fellowworldcitizen, welcome to SO. The question asks how to call built-in LAPACK routines from MATLAB. Your answer has good references but it is not a real answer to the question.