# Where to locate the Intel MKL in Matlab

Tags: matlab, intel-mkl

I have a MATLAB subscription and I have read that MATLAB uses Intel MKL libraries but I am not sure where to locate all the DLLs / files corresponding to the Intel MKL libraries. I could find any mention of their location in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the library at `[matlabroot]\bin\ARCH\mkl.dll` (e.g. C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mkl.dll), but this is just the runtime library. <s>I don't think there is anything you can do with it.</s> To actually develop with Intel MKL, you will need the headers, libraries, etc., <s>which can only be obtained by [purchasing the product](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-purchase)</s>. It seems that MATLAB provides [instructions on how to use LAPACK and BLAS functions from MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-lapack-and-blas-functions-from-mex-files.html) via the import libraries `libmwblas.lib` and `libmwlapack.lib` in `extern\lib\[arch]\[compiler]`. It is not clear if it is possible and/or permissible to build non-MEX or generally MATLAB-independent applications using these libraries.

By the way, this `mkl.dll` was probably built using a procedure similar to [the one posted here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-matlab), which was a typical way of replacing ATLAS with MKL before MathWorks went ahead and did it for everyone, which by the way was a glorious day. However, these instructions seem to be intended for just getting the most recent version of MKL.

Comment: actually you can write MEX-files and call BLAS/LAPACK functions from the Intel MKL implementation. See the second part of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440839/97160) for an example. This is in fact officially [documented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-lapack-and-blas-functions-from-mex-files.html).

Comment: @Amro OK, I stand corrected.  Do you really have full access to the entire set of functionality available with the actual MKL API???

Comment: You can view the functions exported by `mkl.dll` inside "Dependency Walker". It is for most part BLAS/LAPACK functions. MATLAB provides import libraries for those, and the prototypes of those functions are well known. I'm not sure about the rest...

Comment: @Amro Deleting my answer, but I'd be curious to see a non-MEX (MATLAB-independent) application example using some LAPACK or BLAS function. Are the import libraries packaged with MATLAB no-strings-attached? I'm shocked Intel is OK with their product available for use in applications not requiring MATLAB installed to run. Purchasing MATLAB really gets you MKL? Wow.

Comment: no need to delete the answer! As for Intel, I understand that once you purchase a license for MKL, you are free to redistribute the **binaries** with your application... Then again I'm not a lawyer, so better refer to their FAQ first :) http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-licensing-faq

Comment: @Amro Certainly you can redistribute the runtime libraries if you've not statically linked, but as for providing libmwblas.lib and libmwlapack.lib allowing you to call any BLAS/LAPACK function... I'd expect there to be language in the license prohibiting merely generating a wrapper for the product.  :)

Comment: truth is it doesnt matter if you only had DLLs without LIBs; You see import libraries are only needed for MS VC++ compiler/linker (in fact you [could](http://www.coderetard.com/2009/01/21/generate-a-lib-from-a-dll-with-visual-studio/) generate those .lib files yourself using only using the DLLs). MinGW/GCC compiler is able to directly link against a DLL without an import library.

Comment: Good point, but I'm talking about what is permissible. Is it OK to use the dll outside of a MATLAB application? Seems highly dubious. Whether you can link against it, or generate a stub .lib via a def file is another matter, I think! But I guess that would make it the user's legal burden, not MathWorks'.

Comment: @Amro, chappjc, suppose hypothetically, it was OK to use the mkl.dll outside of a MATLAB application. Is there any easy way to use it with R?

Comment: @uday: I dont know how easy this is, but I found this article about compiling R with MKL support: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r . Of course it mentions the official MKL framework, not one extracted from another product :)

Comment: @uday: btw Intel has a special license for Linux users developing non-commercial software, where you can download their entire compiler suite including the MKL libraries: http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development

Comment: @Amro: I use this for playing with IPP at home. Good suggestion.