# SVD method in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, svd

In MATLAB we use this code for calculate U,S,V matrices by SVD method.

```
[U,S,V] = svd(A);
```

Is any way and implemented function in Visual C++ 2012 for using this method? WHat headers needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047503/lapack-svd-singular-value-decomposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is anything like this specifically in/for VS 2012.
My recommendation, try the Eigen matrix library, for example the JacobiSVD. It provides the matrices U S V. Here is an example usage:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html

I use Eigen a lot and it is not difficult to integrate it into your existing code.