# Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) in C

Tags: c, computer-vision, svd

I am doing the five point essential matrix estimation in C where I need to implement SVD. I found an opensource implementation in c [http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dicook/JSS/paper/code/svd.c](http://SVD%20decomposition%20routine.) that works on mxn matrices where m>n. The problem is that the matrix that I want to decompose is a (5x9) matrix and therefore n>m. I need the right orthogonal transformation matrix v where svd(A)=u*d*v'
To ensure (m>n) I tried to do svd(transpose(A))=u2*d2*v2
I found that u=v2, but v is different from u2 and I need v. 
How to implement SVD in C successfully for an 5x9 matrix?

Comment: If your dimensions are not right, sometimes you can fill the matrix up to square with zero rows.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but for future reference one can obtain a SVD implementation in C from the book *"Numerical Recipes in C by William H. Press et al"*, in Chapter 2.6, Page 67, SVD Algorithm. To quote the book

> Here is the algorithm for constructing the singular value decomposition of any
>   matrix.

So I'm assuming the matrix to be decomposed can be square, `m < n` or `n < m`

**Warning**: When googling SVD implementations in C check what assumptions are made w.r.t the input matrix. Some assume the matrix is square, some do not, etc...

Alternatively, you can use the SVD in LAPACK. Stephen Canon provided a code example on another SO question on how to use `dgesdd` to perform SVD. (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047503/lapack-svd-singular-value-decomposition))

Comment: Never late to the party. Thanks.